# tensorflowをanacondaのJupyterで使いたいです

Tags: python, python3, tensorflow, anaconda

#### 発生している問題・エラー

tensorflowをanacondaのJupyterで使いたいです。

http://trafalbad.hatenadiary.jp/entry/2017/03/10/165408
↑
このサイトを参考に進めていたのですがanaconda-Navigatorから左のリストのEnvironmentsで新しくtensor flowをCreateというボタンを使って作りました。
新しく作ったtensor flowからopen terminalを開いて`pip install tensorflow`と打ちたいのですが[プロセスが完了しました]と出て打ち込めません。
open terminalを開くと下のようになります。

```
エラーメッセージ> Last login: Fri Jun  9 15:39:08 on ttys000
/Users/shintarou/.anaconda/navigator/a.tool ; exit;
tadashintarounoMacBook-Pro:~ shintarou$ /Users/shintarou/.anaconda/navigator/a.tool ; exit;
pyenv: bash: command not found
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
Deleting expired sessions...none found.
```

#### 試したこと

Not installed からSeachしてtensorflowを見つけようとしてもありませんでした。

#### 補足情報(言語/FW/ツール等のバージョンなど)

python
macを使っています
anacondaを一度アンインストールしたので関係があるのかもと思っています
terminalで`python`と打ち込めば下のように出ます

```
Python 3.5.3 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Mar  6 2017, 12:15:08) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/79723

Answer (score 1, accepted):

terminalで以下のコマンドを打ってインストールしてください。

```
conda install tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

gHtQo0mbFjnpQz7Fさんの回答ってどうなんですか？
http://geisterhacker.com/index.php/2017/04/26/conda-command/
上記サイトで確認してみてください。

```
conda install tensorflow
```

をそのまま実行すると、anaconda-navigatorで言うとenvironmentsのroot環境にtensorflowがインストールされるだけのはずです。

本件は「tensor flow」と命名した仮想環境にtensorflowをインストールしたいはずです。
一応コマンド操作で言うと

```
conda create --name <仮想環境名>  python=<バージョン>
```

createコマンドで仮想環境名と使用するpythonのバージョンを選んだ後、この環境をactivateさせてpipコマンドを使うべきです。

ただ、私もmacでanaconda-navigatorをコマンドからインストールし、GUIからターミナルを開こうとすると、
「プロセスが完了しました」と出てターミナルが使用できません。
普段はGPU演算を行いたいのでwindowsを使ってますが、windowsなら問題なくターミナルが開きました。
また、macでも普通にインストーラーを使用すれば問題なく出来ました。
ですので、うまく環境変数等を設定しきれてないんでしょうね。

すみません私もこの件の正しい回答を知りたいです。

Comment: スタックオーバーフローへようこそ！
まず、質問に対する補足情報ありがとうございます！

そしてこの回答投稿についてですが、今のところいくつかコメントがついている通り、新しい疑問についての投稿は、回答として投稿するのは推奨されません。
これはスタックオーバーフローが質問・回答形式に特化して設計されているからです。
今回の場合は、今現状の投稿に対して新たな疑問点を、新たな質問として投稿しながら元の投稿 (この質問) に言及するのがよいと思います。

よろしければ、上記対応をご検討頂けませんでしょうか？